# Problem INS-35423 on installing Oracle 11g RAC (empty cluster nodes)

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-rac

I am trying to install Oracle 11g RAC for training purposes on a CentOS 6.9 machine.

I have succesfully installed the grid and clusterware services and have two nodes (`rac01, rac02`)

The following does not report any serious problem

```
./cluvfy stage -pre dbinst -n rac01,rac02
```

As a matter of fact the only problem reported is a missing `pdksh` package (which is not a real problem) and the fact the pool of NTP servers used by the nodes return different IP addresses for each node (to be expected since the pool does not always return the same IP address).

Similary the following reports that clusterware services are up and running

```
[root@rac01 bin]# ./crsctl check cluster -all
**************************************************************
rac01:
CRS-4537: Cluster Ready Services is online
CRS-4529: Cluster Synchronization Services is online
CRS-4533: Event Manager is online
**************************************************************
rac02:
CRS-4537: Cluster Ready Services is online
CRS-4529: Cluster Synchronization Services is online
CRS-4533: Event Manager is online
**************************************************************
```

I am trying to install the database as the `oracle` user but when the time comes to select a RAC installation no nodes are reported.

Does anybody have any clue what other possible problems may exist and how/where to look?

[image: Picture showing the Oracle 11G Installation Wizard]

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the following worked (someone else may explain it) but I re-run the grid installer from each of the nodes as follows

```
[oracle@rac01] rac01$ /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/oui/bin/runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs -updateNodeList ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/11.2.0/grid "CLUSTER_NODES={rac01,rac02}" CRS=true LOCAL_NODE=rac01

[oracle@rac02] rac02$ /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/oui/bin/runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs -updateNodeList ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/11.2.0/grid "CLUSTER_NODES={rac01,rac02}" CRS=true LOCAL_NODE=rac02
```

and afterwards I re-run the db installer and the rac nodes appeared in the list